# I get a permission error while trying to connect windows server to ansible via certificate authentication, what could be a fix for this?

Tags: ansible

[image]

This is an error we have gotten while trying to configure our windows server to ansible. Does anyone know what a fix could be?

Comment: please the next time, to put the error as code in your post

Comment: i think you have to use the [win_ping module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/win_ping_module.html)